# Why it does not remove the line breaks?

Tags: python, regex, django, python-3.x, django-models

Why it does not remove the line breaks?
Number of pages determines line breaks are not removed.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.full_text = re.sub('\n+', '', self.full_text)
    self.pages_count = str(math.ceil(len(self.full_text.split(' ')) / 20))
    super(Book, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: can't you use `self.full_text = self.full_text.replace('\n', '')` ?

Comment: Or `self.full_text = ''.join(self.full_text.split('\n'))`. In fact, your code works for me.

Comment: @DYZ removes but does not save

Comment: Then please provide the full model definition.  as @DYZ said, the snippet of code that you posted works fine.  Also, is there any concern that your full text might also have `\r` in it?

Comment: @DYZ http://pastebin.com/YJjijc7U

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify self.fulltext, the re.sub is OK, if you use @property, you will get an error. Here is what you will expect, self.fulltext will not change.

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python
    import unittest
    import re

    class Attribute(object):
        def __init__(self):
            self.fulltext = 'a\nb\nc\n\n1\n2\n'

        def remove_newline(self, text):
            txt_new = text
            txt_new = re.sub('\n+', '', txt_new)
            return txt_new

        def remove_newline_class_attr(self):
            self.fulltext = re.sub('\n+', '', self.fulltext)
            return self.fulltext

    class TestAttribute(unittest.TestCase):

        def setUp(self):
            attr = Attribute()
            self.attr = attr
            self.txt_wo_newline = 'abc12'

        def test_remove_newline(self):
            fulltext = self.attr.fulltext
            txt = self.attr.remove_newline(fulltext)
            self.assertEquals(txt, self.txt_wo_newline)

        def test_property_no_change(self):
            fulltext = self.attr.fulltext
            txt = self.attr.remove_newline_class_attr()
            self.assertEquals(txt, self.attr.fulltext)

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        suite = unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromTestCase(TestAttribute)
        unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=2).run(suite)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved a problem

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.full_text = self.full_text.split('\r\n')
    self.pages = str(math.ceil(len(self.full_text.split(' ')) / 20))
    super(Book, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```